# Количество пользователей online в чате на node.js и socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Добрый день, делаю чат на nodejs и socket.io. Как получить количество пользователей, которые авторизировались и находятся online в чате. Мне просто нужно учитывать что пользователь может зайти с разных устройств одновременно, но количество должно показываться именно сколько авторизировались. Делаю стандартно:

```
var connect_user = 0; //количество людей
var users_chat = []; //массив


var on_user = users_chat.indexOf(socket.handshake.session.passport.user.user_id); //проверяю id user
if (on_user == -1) {
    //если id нет в массиве, то его добавляю
    var user_id = socket.handshake.session.passport.user.user_id;
    users_chat.push(user_id);
    io.sockets.emit('user_left', {
        connect_user: connect_user + 1
    });
    socket.broadcast.emit('message', {
        send: {
            time: (new Date).toLocaleTimeString(),
            nickname: 'admin',
            message: 'Кто-то зашёл в чат.'
        }
    });
} else {
//иначе оставляю, как есть
    io.sockets.emit('user_left', {
        connect_user: connect_user
    });
}
```

У меня не получается реализовать выход пользователя. Делаю так:

```
var off_user = connect_user.indexOf(socket.handshake.session.passport.user.user_id);
if (off_user != -1) {
    connect_user.splice(off_user, 1);
}
```

Если пользователь вышел с одного устройства, то количество пользователей уменьшается. А мне надо сделать проверку.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Socket.io таким не занимается и не должен. Это задача уровнем выше.